# How to merge all maps of an observables array created with FROM

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm creating an array of observables with FROM operator, every observable is transformed with margeMap.
First, the item is added to a repository with this uploadService.addFile, then if File is not marked as uploaded, then I do the upload with uploadService.uploadFile, this service emits upload progress so I add a filter to only get emitions when file is uploaded or is not uploaded

What I want to do is only have one emition indicanting that all files are already uploaded

I tried use forkJoin, but with that operator I dont have any emition, I think is because in some moment I need to indicate operation is complete inside last pipe but I don't have any idea in how to do this.

```js
/*this.therapyFiles this is an array of elements*/
from(this.therapyFiles).pipe(
      mergeMap(therapyFile => this.fileParser.parseTherapyEndTime(therapyFile.file).pipe(
        map(date => {
          therapyFile.endTime = date;
          return therapyFile;
        })
      )),
      mergeMap(therapyFile =>
        this.uploadService.addFile(
          this.facilityId,
          therapyFile.idDevice,
          therapyFile.file.name,
          therapyFile.endTime
        ).pipe(
          switchMap(file => file.isUploaded ?
            of(this.AlreadyUploaded) :
            this.uploadService.uploadFile(therapyFile.file)),
          map(progress => {
            therapyFile.uploadProgress = progress;
            return therapyFile;
          }),
          filter(uploadedFile => uploadedFile.uploadProgress > 99 || uploadedFile.uploadProgress < 0)
        )
      )
    ).subscribe(z => console.log(z)); // here I get all emition for every item in therapyFiles
```

```js
/*this.therapyFiles this is an array of elements*/
forkJoin(from(this.therapyFiles).pipe(
      mergeMap(therapyFile => this.fileParser.parseTherapyEndTime(therapyFile.file).pipe(
        map(date => {
          therapyFile.endTime = date;
          return therapyFile;
        })
      )),
      mergeMap(therapyFile =>
        this.uploadService.addFile(
          this.facilityId,
          therapyFile.idDevice,
          therapyFile.file.name,
          therapyFile.endTime
        ).pipe(
          switchMap(file => file.isUploaded ?
            of(this.AlreadyUploaded) :
            this.uploadService.uploadFile(therapyFile.file)),
          map(progress => {
            therapyFile.uploadProgress = progress;
            return therapyFile;
          }),
          filter(uploadedFile => uploadedFile.uploadProgress > 99 || uploadedFile.uploadProgress < 0)
        )
      )
    )).subscribe(z => console.log(z)); // I tried in this way but never get an emition, but all inside code of forkjoin works as expected
```

I expect only  have one emition indicating that all files are uploaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I find out that 
in first pipe, fileParser.parseTherapyEndTime is using a subject to emits his results, but that subject was not completed with the complete() method, all invocations of that service does never finalize and all combining operators requires that all inner observables are finalized.
So i added complete() method inside fileParser.parseTherapyEndTime 
 and also I use **toArray()** rxjs operator combine all emitions into an array that is the desired behavior.

I update my code in this way:

```js
    from(this.therapyFiles).pipe(
      mergeMap(therapyFile => this.fileParser.parseTherapyEndTime(therapyFile.file)
      .pipe(
        map(date => {
          therapyFile.endTime = date;
          return therapyFile;
        })
      )),
      mergeMap(therapyFile =>
        this.uploadService.addFile(
          this.facilityId,
          therapyFile.idDevice,
          therapyFile.file.name,
          therapyFile.endTime
        )
        .pipe(
          switchMap(file => file.isUploaded ?
            of(this.AlreadyUploaded) :
            this.uploadService.uploadFile(therapyFile.file)),
          map(progress => {
            therapyFile.uploadProgress = progress;
            return therapyFile;
          }),
          filter(uploadedFile => uploadedFile.uploadProgress > 99 || uploadedFile.uploadProgress === this.AlreadyUploaded)
        ),
      ),
      toArray()
    ).subscribe(() => {
      this.uploadedFiles = true;
    });
```

Sorry for my bad english but I'm still practicing

Answer (score 0):

use concatAll

```js
   of(this.therapyFiles).pipe(
      mergeMap(therapyFile => this.fileParser.parseTherapyEndTime(therapyFile.file).pipe(
        map(date => {
          therapyFile.endTime = date;
          return therapyFile;
        })
      )),
      mergeMap(therapyFile =>
        this.uploadService.addFile(
          this.facilityId,
          therapyFile.idDevice,
          therapyFile.file.name,
          therapyFile.endTime
        ).pipe(
          switchMap(file => file.isUploaded ?
            of(this.AlreadyUploaded) :
            this.uploadService.uploadFile(therapyFile.file)),
          map(progress => {
            therapyFile.uploadProgress = progress;
            return therapyFile;
          }),
          filter(uploadedFile => uploadedFile.uploadProgress > 99 || uploadedFile.uploadProgress < 0)
        )
      ),
      concatAll()
    ).subscribe(z => console.log(z)); // I tried in
```

Comment: If I try to use concatAll without changing the initial FROM to OF, it makes an error,
if I'm not mistaken, if I use OF instead of FROM, I will have an emission with all the elements of the array, but what I need is to have an emission for each element of the array,